# Is there a bracha achrona called "Al Ha'Adama"?

Tags: blessing, food, tosfot

[This](http://berachot.org/halacha/26_Bracha_on_Snack_Bars.html) Web page alludes (at Footnote 2) to a discussion of the possibility that the correct bracha after raw grain is "Al HaAdama":

> 2. Tosfot 37a D"H HaKoses has a doubt that perhaps the Bracha Achrona for raw grain is Al HaAdama.

I had never heard of such a bracha achrona. Does it/did it exist? What is/was it? Do we need to say it for anything?

Comment: According to Tosfot we may have to say it. This has practical ramifications. See the OU's article about what beracha and how to each Granola Bars: https://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-kosher/what-beracha-does-one-recite-on-a-granola-bar/

Comment: @Menachem Summary: Modern *poskim* don't rule that this *b'racha* practically should be recited, but it's best not to put oneself into a situation where it is possible that that's the appropriate *b'racha acharona*. Therefore, it is best to eat granola bars slowly enough that you eat less than a (large) *k'zayis* of oats per *k'dei achilas p'ras*. In such a case, if you ate more than a *k'zayis* of granola bar in that time span (but less than a large *k'zayis* of actual oats), you can recite a (sufficiently) doubt-free *borei n'fashos*. Likewise if you ate faster, but you ought not eat faster.

Comment: Rabbi Yehudah had a much richer variety of berakhos than we do. Judging from the Yerushalmi, Israeli Jewry also had far more kinds of berakhos than the Babylonians, perhaps following this tradition. As I wrote before http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/66337/1570 , early Ashkenaz bore many more signs of Israeli practice than did Sepharadim and the geonim. This is one of those things...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Bracha Al Haadama is cited in tosfot Brachot in name of the machzor of Rabenu Tam (an annotation written by Rabbenu tam in his Machzor), Tosfot said also that Rabenu Tam further reversed his position. The bracha was a birkat Me'en shalosh (as al hamichia or al haets or al hagefen for 7 species of fruits for which torah praised the country of Israel) but was not mentioned in Chazal. The need for such a bracha was for Bracha Acharona after raw wheat eating, when the Bracha Rishona is Bore Peri Haadama.
I will give some quotes.

Tosfot Brachot 37a:

> ומיהו בלאחריו יש לספק מאי מברכין אם מברכין על המחיה ועל הכלכלה ומסיים על האדמה ועל פרי האדמה דלא אשכחן ברכת על המחיה ועל הכלכלה אלא היכא דבריך עלייהו ברישא קודם אכילה בורא מיני מזונות ***ור''ת הגיה במחזור שלו על האדמה ועל פרי האדמה כו' וחזר בו דלא אשכחן בשום מקום הך ברכה*** דלקמן (דף מד.) מפרש ברכה אחת מעין ג' וקאמר בחמשת המינים על הארץ ועל המחיה ועל ז' המינים על הארץ ועל הפירות ועל האדמה ועל פרי האדמה לא הזכיר

*Conclusion*
such Bracha is discussed only after, not before eating. Today fairly sure that this Bracha is not practiced.

---

*A couple of Brachot mentioned in chazal before eating (not ruled in Halacha)*

For veggies Bore mine deshayim is mentioned. In Yerushalmi Bore Mine Zer'onim is mentioned for raw wheat and rice.

> הכוסס את החיטין אומר עליו בורא מיני זרעונים
>
> הכוסס את האורז אומר עליו בורא מיני זרעונין אפיו ובישלו אע"פ שהפרוסות קיימות אומר עליו בורא מיני מזונות

For rice Bore mine Maadanim is also mentioned

> ר"ש חסידא אומר בורא מיני מעדנים

Comment: Thanks! Does anyone think we still need to say this today?

Comment: thank you, may be good to modify the tittle of the question

Comment: @SAH fixed for saying it today, not ruled

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/26033/759

Comment: "eliminated" sounds like it was practiced (by not only him) and he did away with the practice. That's not what you mean — or is it?

Comment: @msh210 I will try to make this as in text: הגיה במחזור שלו... וחזר בו

Comment: @msh210 "reversed his position" is good?

Comment: Yes, it is, IMO.